# shared probability of all paths between tow nodes in a weighted limited graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, reliability

I have an undirected weighted graph $G=(V,E)$

In this graph, the weight of the edge $(v[i],v[j])$ is the probity $p$ of a direct transition between $v[i]$ and $v[j]$ ($0<p<1$).

[image: graph example]

I am trying to calculate the probability of transition between $2$ nodes $v, u$.

What I did so far:

I found all paths from $v$ to $u$ (using all_simple_paths)

$[v -0.1 \to a -0.2 \to c -0.3 \to u]$

$[v -0.1 \to a -0.2 \to c -0.2 \to b -0.4 \to d -0.5 \to u]$

$[v -0.1 \to b -0.2 \to c -0.3 \to u]$

$[v -0.1 \to b -0.4 \to d -0.5 \to u]$

but I don't sure how to union the probability of the different paths with shared nodes. I think I can do that by union and intersection between paths, but I'm searching after a simple programable algorithm.

Comment: Is the graph directed? I.e., the edge from $A$ to $V$ is labeled $0.1$, so does that mean from $A$, there is a $0.1$ chance to move to $V$, and from $V$, there is a $0.1$ chance to move back to $A$?

Comment: Undirected, but you can't go back

Comment: If there's a $0.1$ probability of a transition from $V$ to $A$, and a $0.1$ probability of a transition from $V$ to $B$, where do you go from $V$ in the other cases (with probability $0.8$)? The same question arises for the other nodes.